# Error: This is R 3.1.3, package ‘weightr’ needs >= 3.3.3

Tags: r, package

I updated my RStudio and cannot get the weightr package to install. This was after trying to first install weightr from the console and downloading the tar file from cran-r. Is there something else I can do to get this to work?

Comment: You need a more up-to-date version of R not a more up-to-date version of R studio. Try to update R to the most recent version and then reinstall weightr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade R separately from RStudio.  The current version of R is 3.5.1, and can be found at https://cran.rstudio.com/ or https://cran.r-project.org/.

Comment: Great, I downloaded the newer version of R and it seems to be working, thank you!

Comment: @LobstaBoy you might consider "accepting" the answer, if it solved your problem.